# Using array variable in SQL select statement returns "Array to string conversion"

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a compound statement where it will select threads where the 'node_id' column is in an array of values set in $node_ids

```
$node_ids = ['13', '14'];
$db = $this->app->db();
return $db->fetchAllColumn($db->limit("
        SELECT thread_id
        FROM xf_thread
        WHERE thread_id > ?
        AND node_id in " . $node_ids . "
        ORDER BY thread_id
    ", $batch
), $start);
```

However I get an error

> Array to string conversion

on the line with:

```
AND node_id in " . $node_ids . "
```

Comment: You should tag the framework you use.

Comment: Ok added another tag

Comment: `$node_ids` is an array. You can only concatenate strings. Use `implode()` to convert the array to a comma-delimited string.

Comment: And don't forget that you need `()` around the list: `node_id in (13, 14)`

Comment: But it would be better to use a prepared statement with parameters instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Fixed by changing to this line: `AND node_id in (" . implode(',', $node_ids) . ")`

Comment: @RobertIannicca if resolved, you should consider self-answering the question by clicking the "Add an Answer" below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works based on comment by Barmar:

```
$node_ids = ['13', '14'];
$db = $this->app->db();
return $db->fetchAllColumn($db->limit("
        SELECT thread_id
        FROM xf_thread
        WHERE thread_id > ?
        AND node_id in (" . implode(',', $node_ids) . ")
        ORDER BY thread_id
    ", $batch
), $start);
```